# How to apply an aggregating function to groups of table (or dataset) rows?

Tags: matlab, aggregate, accumarray, matlab-table

Suppose I have some [**`table`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) (or [**`dataset`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset.html)) object `A` that includes some factor `X` (having *n* distinct values, or "levels") among its variables.  Also suppose I have some custom aggregating function `agg` that takes as input a sequence of rows, and returns a single summary number (aka "aggregate") as output.

An example of an *extremely* common operation in statistically data analysis would be to group the rows of `A` according to the value of the `X` factor, and to apply `agg` to the arrays consisting of the rows in the group.  The result of such an operation should be a new `table` (or `dataset`, depending on the class of `A`), with *n* rows and two variables.  The first one of these variables should be named `X`, and should contain the *n* distinct values of the `X` factor in `A`, and the second should have some suitable (preferably user-specified) name, and should contain the result of applying `agg` to the row groups for the corresponding `X` levels.

As I said, this is a very standard operation to perform on data structures such as MATLAB's `table` and `dataset` objects, so I was expecting there'd be a built-in way to do it, but I'm not finding it.

---

For example, let `A` be as defined below:

```
% "data" table
A = cell2table({
                'even', 'red', 'spades', 38, 0.9837;
                'even', 'red', 'hearts', 19, 0.5695;
                'even', 'red', 'diamonds', 89, 0.2629;
                'even', 'red', 'diamonds', 98, 0.3578;
                'even', 'red', 'diamonds', 92, 0.2596;
                'even', 'red', 'diamonds', 69, 0.5751;
                'even', 'red', 'diamonds', 77, 0.6318;
                'even', 'yellow', 'clubs', 22, 0.6917;
                'even', 'green', 'spades', 35, 0.6674;
                'even', 'green', 'hearts', 67, 0.7896;
                'even', 'green', 'hearts', 49, 0.5025;
                'even', 'green', 'hearts', 64, 0.5318;
                'odd', 'red', 'spades', 22, 0.5587;
                'odd', 'red', 'hearts', 51, 0.9122;
                'odd', 'red', 'diamonds', 74, 0.3343;
                'odd', 'red', 'diamonds', 69, 0.2911;
                'odd', 'yellow', 'spades', 33, 0.2653;
                'odd', 'yellow', 'spades', 38, 0.2549;
                'odd', 'yellow', 'diamonds', 1, 0.2064;
                'odd', 'yellow', 'diamonds', 25, 0.8257;
                'odd', 'green', 'spades', 64, 0.4348;
                'odd', 'green', 'hearts', 59, 0.8644;
                'odd', 'green', 'hearts', 4, 0.6374;
                'odd', 'green', 'hearts', 11, 0.3354
               }, 'VariableNames', ...
               {'Parity', 'TrafficLight', 'Suit', 'order', 'prevalence'});
```

Also, let `X` be `TrafficLight`, and `agg` be

```
agg = @(t) size(t, 1);
```

(Of course, I'm using this `agg` here just to keep the example as simple as possible.  In practice `agg` will be far less simple-minded.)

The typical `group_aggregate` function I'm thinking of usually takes as input arguments (in some order) an aggregating function, the name of the column in the output for the computed aggregates, a `table` (or `dataset`), and the names of one or more variables to group by.  Therefore, in this example, the call to such a function, and its output, would look something like this

```
>> group_aggregate(agg, 'nrows', A, {'TrafficLight'})

ans =

    TrafficLight    nrows
    ____________    _____

    'green'          8   
    'red'           11   
    'yellow'         5
```

BTW, to get the result above, I conjured up this desperate little beast:

```
>> tmp = cellfun(@(s) {s agg(A(strcmp(A.TrafficLight, s), :))}, ...
unique(A.TrafficLight), 'un', 0);
>> cell2table(cat(1, tmp{:}), 'VariableNames', {'TrafficLight' 'nrows'})
```

I hope that a built-in solution is more robust to, for example, different classes of values for the `X` variable, etc.

Comment: But that's such a lovely little beast!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a `table` method just for this purpose, but for aggregation, look to [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
>> [lights,ia,ic]=unique(A.TrafficLight);
>> nrows = accumarray(ic,1);
>> cell2table([lights num2cell(nrows)],'VariableNames', {'TrafficLight' 'nrows'})
ans = 
    TrafficLight    nrows
    ____________    _____
    'green'          8   
    'red'           11   
    'yellow'         5
```

Comment: As it turns out, unfortunately, `accumarray` is [seriously buggy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21689558/559827).

Comment: @kjo Curious.  Can you expand?  One thing to note is the first input _should_ be sorted. You just need to ensure the input is sorted to be sure.

Comment: Yes, in my comment I linked to a post I just sent to SO, with all the gory details.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is 1 year old...

I use a different way that accumarray. I use tabulate
http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tabulate.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop

I also still have an older version of Matlab and I use therefore dataset. In this case (but I think it might also work for 'table'), your code would be:

```
TrafficLight_stats=tabulate(A.TrafficLight);
Agg_table=mat2dataset(TrafficLight_stats,'VarNames',{'TrafficLight','nrows','Perc'});

Agg_table = 

TrafficLight    nrows       Perc         
'red'           [11]        [45.8333]
'yellow'        [ 5]        [20.8333]
'green'         [ 8]        [33.3333]
```